# Can't log richtext string of a cell because of data validation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rtf, richtext

My cell F394 looks like this:

08/10/2023
And there is a link attached to it (not as hyperlink, but as RichText).

Data validation is active and allows for short date only in exactly this format (dd/mm/yyyy).

I want to obtain/log the URL that's attached via a script:

```
function logURLToCloudLogs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F394"); 
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();

  for (var i = 0; i < richTextValue.getTextRuns().length; i++) {
    var textRun = richTextValue.getTextRuns()[i];
    if (textRun.getLinkUrl()) {
      var linkUrl = textRun.getLinkUrl();
      Logger.log("URL:" + linkUrl);
      return;
    }
  }

  Logger.log("Cell contains no URL.");
}
```

But it results in error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTextRuns')
> logURLToCloudLogs   @ ShowDateEdit.gs:7

When I log the value of the cell via .getValue(), i get:

> Sun Oct 08 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2023

My suspicion is that, due to the data validation, apps script does not identify the string as richtext.

Can anyone help me successfully log the richtext & obtain the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing error message and the value of `Sun Oct 08 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2023` by `getValues`, I guessed that your cell value of "F394" might be the date object. In that case, such an error occurs. Because `cell.getRichTextValue()` is null. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function logURLToCloudLogs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("F394"); 
  var orgNumberFormats = cell.getNumberFormats();
  cell.setNumberFormat("@");
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  cell.setNumberFormats(orgNumberFormats);
  var runs = richTextValue.getRuns();
  for (var i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
    var textRun = runs[i];
    if (textRun.getLinkUrl()) {
      var linkUrl = textRun.getLinkUrl();
      Logger.log("URL:" + linkUrl);
      return;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Cell contains no URL.");
}
```

- In this modification, the cell format is changed to the text format. And, the richtectValue is retrieved. And, the cell format is changed to the original one.
- I thought that the following modification might be able to be also used.

  ```js
  function logURLToCloudLogs() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getRange("F394"); 
    var orgNumberFormats = cell.getNumberFormats();
    cell.setNumberFormat("@");
    var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
    cell.setNumberFormats(orgNumberFormats);
    var linkUrl = richTextValue.getLinkUrl();
    if (linkUrl) {
      Logger.log("URL:" + linkUrl);
      return;
    }
    Logger.log("Cell contains no URL.");
  }
  ```
- By the way, Class RichTextValue has no method of `getTextRuns()`. In this case, it might be [`getRuns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getRuns()). Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- Even when Sheets API can be used, the hyperlink can be retrieved. But, from your script, when Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, I thought that it might be useful. So, I proposed the above modification.

#### References:

- [getNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNumberFormats())
- [setNumberFormats(numberFormats)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)

Comment: Thanks so much. Both of your scripts work like a charm. Some heroes don't wear capes!

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Here's a follow-up question that's closely related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77223281/obtain-url-from-richtext-from-value-before-edit
Maybe you can help?