# Obtain URL from richtext from value before edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, datepicker, rtf

Column F of my script has date validation (short date) activated.
All cells in column F contain richtext with an URL to a calendar event:

[image]

Every time column F is edited (= set to a new date), I want my script to access the calendar event, and update it to the new date.
(This is not part of my problem, but explains what I want to achieve in the end).
EDIT: Here's my entire script:

```
function DateEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedColumn = editedRange.getColumn();
  
  if (editedColumn == 6) {

  // Get event URL
      var orgNumberFormats = editedRange.getNumberFormats();
      editedRange.setNumberFormat("@");
      var richTextValue = editedRange.getRichTextValue();
      editedRange.setNumberFormats(orgNumberFormats);
      var eventUrl = richTextValue.getLinkUrl();

      // Get event ID
      if (eventUrl) {
        var eventIdEncoded = eventUrl.split("/").pop(); // Get the encoded part from the URL
        try {
          eventIdEncoded = eventIdEncoded.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'); // Revert URL-safe Base64 encoding
          eventIdEncoded += "==".substring(0, 2 - eventIdEncoded.length % 2); // Add padding if needed
          var eventIdDecoded = Utilities.base64Decode(eventIdEncoded);
          
          var eventId = Utilities.newBlob(eventIdDecoded).getDataAsString();
          var decodeEventId = eventId.split(" ")[0];
    
        } catch (e) {
          Logger.log("Error decoding and extracting the event ID: " + e);
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("Cell contains no URL.");
      }

    // Edit Event
    try {
      var newDateStr = editedRange.getValue(); // Assuming the date is in "dd/mm/yyyy" format

      // Split the date string into parts
      var dateParts = newDateStr.split('/');
      var day = dateParts[0];
      var month = dateParts[1];
      var year = dateParts[2];

      // Create a new Date object with the adjusted date
      var newDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // Subtract 1 from the month because months are zero-based
  
      if (!isNaN(newDate.getTime())) {
        // The date string was successfully converted to a Date object
        // Now, you can proceed with your code to update the event date

        Logger.log("Event ID: " + decodeEventId)
  
        var calendarId = 'XYZSample@group.calendar.google.com'; // Replace with your calendar ID
        var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
        var event = calendar.getEventById(decodeEventId);
  
        if (event) {
          // Get the existing start and end times
          var startTime = event.getStartTime();
          var endTime = event.getEndTime();
  
          // Create new Date objects with the adjusted date but the same time
          var newStartTime = new Date(newDate);
          newStartTime.setHours(startTime.getHours(), startTime.getMinutes());
  
          var newEndTime = new Date(newDate);
          newEndTime.setHours(endTime.getHours(), endTime.getMinutes());
  
          // Update the event's start and end times with the new date
          event.setTime(newStartTime, newEndTime);


Logger.log("Event date updated successfully, and guests have been notified.");
        } else {
          Logger.log("Event not found with ID: " + decodeEventId);
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("Invalid date format in the edited cell: " + newDateStr);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log("Error updating event with ID: " + decodeEventId + "\n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that, if date picker is not used, the URL in the richtext can get overwritten and removed by other users. I have not found a way to preserve the URL in the richtext. I can get the old value from before the edit (e.oldValue), but not the URL.

I need my script to obtain the URL & put it back to the cell as RTF after the date was changed (by default, because it shouldn't matter if other users use the date picker or enter manual dates which match the given validation format).

The URL will not change, as the calendar event stays the same.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: May I know how you add the link in the dates? Do you use [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313) or via Appscript?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Serenity as described, I use richtextbuilder, not hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please set `sheetName`.

And, first, please run `init()` function. By this, the URLs of current cells of column "F" are saved to PropertiesService.

As the next step, please manually modify the value of column "F" on Spreadsheet. By this, `onEdit` is automatically run by the simple trigger. And, the URL is set to the edited cell.

```js
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

// First, please run this function.
function init() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const urls = sheet.getRange("F1:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().map(([f]) => f.getLinkUrl() || "");
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("urls", JSON.stringify(urls));
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 6) return;
  const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const propUrls = prop.getProperty("urls");
  const urls = propUrls ? JSON.parse(propUrls) : [];
  const url = urls[range.rowStart - 1];
  const currentUrl = range.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  if (currentUrl) {
    urls[range.rowStart - 1] = currentUrl;
    prop.setProperty("urls", JSON.stringify(urls));
  } else if (url) {
    range.setRichTextValue(range.getRichTextValue().copy().setLinkUrl(url).build());
  }
}
```

#### IMPORTANT:

- In this script, it supposes that the URL of column "F" is constant. If the URL of column "F" is added and updated, please run the `init()` function. By this, the URLs in PropertiesService are also updated.

#### Note:

- This sample script is a simple sample script for `I need my script to obtain the URL & put it back to the cell as RTF after the date was changed`. Please be careful about this.
- Specification of Properties Service for Google Apps Script can be seen at [this report (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-specification-of-properties-service-for-google-apps-script-198c487f3896). If your situation is over than the current specification of Properties Service, a temporal Spreadsheet might be required to be used.

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [Report: Specification of Properties Service for Google Apps Script](https://medium.com/google-cloud/report-specification-of-properties-service-for-google-apps-script-198c487f3896)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry if my question was not written out clear enough.
I am using installable triggers, and basically all I try to achieve is that the URL in the richtext will be preserved, even if a user overwrites the date manually, removing the URL. I thought the only solution to achieve this, is storing the old URL value somehow in the script, but I just can't find a way to obtain the old URL once the cell value has been overwritten.
I understand your idea with the INIT() function, but I would need something that doesn't need manual execution and comes with the trigger.

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. And, I'm worried that when I saw your reply, I thought that my sample script could achieve your expected result. About `I understand your idea with the INIT() function, but I would need something that doesn't need manual execution and comes with the trigger.`, if you want to automatically save the URLs, how about executing `init` function by the trigger?

Comment: @LionelHutz About `I just can't find a way to obtain the old URL once the cell value has been overwritten`, I think that my script can achieve this. About `but I would need something that doesn't need manual execution and comes with the trigger.`, I think that my script is automatically run by the OnEdit trigger of the simple trigger. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more information on the issue of my answer? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @LionelHutz By the way, `init` function is used for saving the current URLs from column "F". `onEdit` function is automatically run when column "F" is edited. I thought that `basically all I try to achieve is that the URL in the richtext will be preserved, even if a user overwrites the date manually, removing the URL.` can be achieved by my sample script. But, my script is a simple script. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. I'm not sure if I follow you correctly.
If I run the INIT() function with an onEdit trigger, it's already too late because the richtext could already have been overwritten at this time.
Do you think I could solve this problem with a simple onSelectionChange() trigger? because a cell has to be selected by user before the values can be changed. I think this could be the simplest way to solve it.

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. From `If I run the INIT() function with an onEdit trigger, it's already too late because the richtext could already have been overwritten at this time.`, I'm worried that you might misunderstand my proposed script. `init` function is used for saving the current URLs. So, for example, please run `init` manually only one time. After this, please edit the cell of column "F". By this, the URL of the edited cell is back using the saved URLs. Isn't this your expected result?

Comment: Thanks @Tainaike, you are right, but unfortunately, my sheet is constantly being edited & new lines  with dates / rich text values are added all the time. So, the string which you saved in INIT() will become outdated.

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. About `but unfortunately, my sheet is constantly being edited & new lines with dates / rich text values are added all the time. So, the string which you saved in INIT() will become outdated.`, in this case, how about updating the saved URLs by executing `init` when new URLs are added? And, when the new URL is not added, the old URL is copied.

Comment: @LionelHutz Now, I updated my sample script. In that case, when a new URL is added, the PropertiesService is updated and the new URL is saved. When a cell is edited without including a URL, when the old URL has been saved, the old URL is set to the cell. Is this your expected result? In that case, as the initial URLs, please run the `init` function. After this, I think that `init` is not required to be run.

Comment: @LionelHutz I think that from your situation, in order to save the current URLs, it is required to run `init` only one time. Of course, if all cells of column "F" are empty, `init` is not required to be run. After the current URLs are saved, I think that my updated script can be used for your expected result. But, if I misunderstood your actual expected result and situation, I apologize.

Comment: thanks a lot, please don't worry about your english, it's perfect!
I was hoping to find a different approach than your proposed INIT() function, because the way these URL's are added initially, is already through a rather complex function. In general, I want to refrain from having to run a function manually.
Is there a way I can get in touch with you as maybe that's easier if you are eager to help me?

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. About `I was hoping to find a different approach than your proposed INIT() function, because the way these URL's are added initially, is already through a rather complex function.`, in this case, I would like to propose it as a new question. Because in your question, the detailed information about it is not included, and my answer is to update the URL of the edited cell of your initial question.

Comment: @LionelHutz I think that when you separate your question like "Set old URLto edited cell" and "Save current URLs for the way these URL's are added initially, is already through a rather complex function", it will help users think of a solution. I think that one of them has already been resolved by my answer. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I updated the question with my actual code.  Maybe you can see a bit better what I'm trying to do, and why I need everything in one function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255543/discussion-between-lionelhutz-and-tanaike).

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me. I think that when you separate your question like "Set old URLto edited cell" and "Save current URLs for the way these URL's are added initially, is already through a rather complex function", it will help users think of a solution. I think that one of them has already been resolved by my answer. And, please back to your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: see the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244586/set-old-rtf-url-to-edited-cell
Maybe in this question, I provided too many details which can be confusing.

Comment: @LionelHutz Thank you for replying. In your this question, I understand that you wanted to achieve "Set old URLto edited cell". In this case, I think that my answer resolved this. I think that your new question will be "Save current URLs for the way these URL's are added initially, is already through a rather complex function". I will check your new question.