# Set old RTF URL to edited cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, rtf

My column F contains a value in rich text format (rtf) which also contains a URL.

When users edit cells in this column, depending on how they go about it (doubleclick the text, or just one-click the cell and start typing), they are able to overwrite the richtext, and thus the URL disappears.

I need an installable onEdit trigger that saves the old URL, and puts it back to the cell as RTF whenever a cell in column F is edited.

I know I can access the old VALUE (e.oldValue), but I don't know how to access the old URL (as it's in rich text format, and at the time of edit, has already been overwritten).

Any ideas?

PS. I have to work with RTF here, because the column has data validation activated and won't accept a hyperlink.

EDIT: Here's the code used to initially add the URL as rich text.

```
    function ShowStatusEdit(e) {
      const editedColumn = e.range.getColumn(); // Get the edited column number
    
      // Check if the edited column is NOT Column N (index 14)
      if (editedColumn !== 14) {
        return; // Exit the function early
      }
    
      const editedValue = e.value; // Get the edited value
    
      // Continue with logic for Column N edits and "Confirmed" value
      if (editedValue === "Confirmed") {
        const ss = e.source;
        const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        const row = e.range.getRow();
        const eventCategory = sheet.getRange(row, 11).getValue();
        const showDate = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
    
        // Check if the first four characters of eventCategory are not "Sold", "Fest", or "Tour"
        if (eventCategory.indexOf("Sold") !== 0 && eventCategory.indexOf("Fest") !== 0 && eventCategory.indexOf("Tour") !== 0) {
        
      // CALENDAR ENTRY FOR SHOW
        if (showDate instanceof Date) {
          const startTime = new Date(showDate);
          startTime.setHours(19, 0, 0, 0); // Set the time to 19:00
          const endTime = new Date(showDate);
          endTime.setHours(23, 30, 0, 0); // Set the time to 23:30
    
            const calendarId = 'XXXtest@group.calendar.google.com'; // Replace with your calendar ID
            const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
            const eventTitle = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
            const eventDescription = `This is a test event`;
            const guestlist = ['xxxtest@gmail.com'];
    
            const eventOptions = {
              description: eventDescription,
              guests: guestlist.join(),
              sendInvites: true,
              sendUpdates: "all",
            };
    
            const newEvent = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, eventOptions);
    
            // Get the event URL using the CalendarApp event's ID
            var ati = calendar.getId().indexOf("@");
            var splitEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@');
            var EventId = Utilities.base64Encode(splitEventId[0] + " " + calendar.getId().substring(0, ati + 2)).replace(/=/gi, '');
            var eventUrl = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit/" + EventId;
    
            // Format the showDate variable as a string in the "DD/MM/YYYY" format
            var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(showDate, "GMT+0200", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    
            // Create a new rich text value with the event URL
            const richTextWithUrl = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
            .setText(formattedDate)
            .setLinkUrl(eventUrl)
            .build();
    
            // Set the updated rich text value in column 6 (F)
            sheet.getRange(row, 6).setRichTextValue(richTextWithUrl);
    
          } else {
            Logger.log('Invalid show date format: ' + showDate);
          // Handle the case where the show date format is not as expected
          }

}else {
      Logger.log('Event category starts with "Sold," "Fest," or "Tour": ' + eventCategory);
        // Handle the case where the event category starts with "Sold," "Fest," or "Tour"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: About `saves the old URL`, can I ask you about the details of your current situation? Because, from your question, I thought that in your situation, the timing for saving the URL might be important. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to generate the rich text so that we can investigate an appropriate solution for you.

Comment: Hey Lionel, any luck?

Comment: @NEWAZA thanks for your reply.
I understand there is no way to retrieve the URL directly from the cell anymore after cell was edited. So I need to store the link somehow. I'm adding the code to the question which is used to create the URL. I would prefer it if I could somehow store the links without having to have a secret sheet.
Careful: Users can add rows anywhere they want. So can't store a "backup" that is depending on the same row order.

Comment: Hey @NEWAZA were you able to look into it yet?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to access the old URL (as it's in rich text format, and at the time of edit, has already been overwritten).

When a cell is edited, the `oldValue` only provides the old value as a string and nothing more.

An idea could be to create a hidden sheet that stores the current richtext's url/hyperlink. I have a project that does something similar, though stores historical "versions" of links in the hidden sheet.

**Logic:**

> onEdit
>
> - If new value of column is a hyperlink, store to hidden sheet at current row index.
> - If new value (of column) is not a hyperlink, restore from hidden sheet (at current row index).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the code used for initially adding the URL (it's a link to a calendar event). Thanks for letting me know how I can best create an index to store the URL & later on put it back into the cell as RTF if value is adjusted or overwritten.